# Display raw XML from a URL in iframe

Tags: html, xml, iframe

I have a XML in my webserver, when i try to open it in a browser it displays properly as raw xml, but the same when tried to display it in an iframe with its url, it displays as string and not as raw xml.

```
<iframe type="application/xml" src="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qvRzT/8/

Please note that I cannot load xml as a content in iframe because the xml is dynamically generated, I can only use its url to load in iframe.

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario, the XML source from API response will be passed to HTML iframe tag source. Response content type **text/plain** will display plain XML content in html page without parsing

HTML

```
<iframe type="text/plain" data-bind="attr: {src: ('api/document/view?token=' + doc.downloadUrl)}"></iframe>
```

C# API response

```
public HttpResponseMessage View(string token)
{
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
         var localFilePath ="D:\sample.xml";
        var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(localFilePath);
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        string FileMimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileInfo.Name);
        if (FileMimeType == "text/xml")
        {
             result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new 
             System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
         }
         else
              result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(FileMimeType);
         result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
         System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
         result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileInfo.Name;
         return result;
 }
```

Comment: The attribute type="text/plain" at the iframe element didn't change anything for me. But setting the response header "Content-Type" to "text/plain" in the response did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the browser sees the XML as the source of the page. So it will be marked up as an XML file. When the browser gets the iframe and loads the XML, it handles the source as HTML. (Even if no HTML tag is provided.)

Comment: Would you suggest any solution?

Comment: Avoid using an iframe to display the xml. Instead, navigate to the xml.

Comment: What do you mean "navigate to xml"?

Comment: Navigate to the page which contains the XML file: e.g; https://example.net/file.xml or in this case:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml

Comment: any other way to show raw XML content in HTML page in iframe src ?